# Ubuntu is using Intel Compatible controller instead of NVidia

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 3d

I'm trying to run Minecraft  on my Ubuntu 12.04 but I'm having the following error:

> [08:04:00 INFO]: Client> org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
>
> [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>  at
> org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native
> Method) ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?]
> [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>  at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
>
> ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?] [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>     at
> org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:818)
>
> ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?] [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>     at
> org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
>
> ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?] [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>     at
> org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
>
> ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?] [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>     at
> org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
>
> ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?] [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>  at azl.ad(SourceFile:312) [1.7.5.jar:?]
>
> [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>  at azl.f(SourceFile:696) [1.7.5.jar:?]
>
> [08:04:00 INFO]: Client>  at
> net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148) [1.7.5.jar:?]
>
> [08:04:01 INFO]: Client> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display
> ":0".

Looking around the net, I found out my nvidia drivers are not being used, using the following command:

`lsb_release -a && lspci -vmk | grep -A 8 -B 2 VGA && lspci | grep VGA && glxinfo | grep -w 'direct\|OpenGL'`

I get:

> No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:  Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS Release: 12.04 Codename: precise
>
> Device:   00:02.0 Class:  VGA compatible controller Vendor:   Intel
>
> Corporation Device:   4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics
>
> Controller SVendor:   Hewlett-Packard Company SDevice:    Device 1966
>
> Rev:  06 Driver:  i915 Module:    i915
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core
>
> Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) Xlib:  extension
>
> "GLX" missing on display ":0". Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on
>
> display ":0". Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0". Xlib:
>
> extension "GLX" missing on display ":0". Xlib:  extension "GLX"
>
> missing on display ":0". Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or
>
> fbconfig Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0". Xlib:
>
> extension "GLX" missing on display ":0". Xlib:  extension "GLX"
>
> missing on display ":0". Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display
>
> ":0". Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0". Xlib:  extension
>
> "GLX" missing on display ":0". Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on
>
> display ":0".

How can I get the right driver installed and used by default?

BTW, in the Additional Drivers section I see the nvidia driver, but it says that the driver is installed but not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, installing Bumblebee solved my issues.

Here are the steps I followed:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee